# Pressing a button in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, button, streamwriter

I am new to Visual Basic.NET and I am just playing around with it. I have a book that tells me how to read from a file but not how to write to the file with a button click. All I have is a button and a textbox named fullNameBox. When I click the button it gives me an unhandled exception error. Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Sub outputFile()
        Dim oWrite As System.IO.StreamWriter
        oWrite = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\sample.txt")
        oWrite.WriteLine(fullNameBox.Text)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        outputFile()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what is the exception? does it occur on first instance of the click?

Comment: Okay I figured out that it is creating the file it is just not writing anything to it

Comment: Like I said, the easiest way to track this down is stepping through it.  Is fullNameBox actually a valid text box?  Have you tried just writing text to it, without the fullNameBox?  Step through and check your variables.

Comment: After testing a few different things I got everything to work. I had to change the way I was outputting to the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried stepping through your application to see where the error is?  With a quick glance, it looks like you might need to use System.IO.File on the fourth line (oWrite = IO.File...) instead of just IO, but I haven't tried to run it.

Comment: I changed it, but it still didnt work. The program gives me no errors until I click the button then it gives me the unhandled exception error

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the function and then stepping through to see what line is causing the problem?  "Unhandled Exception" is not a very helpful error, it just means something went wrong that you didn't account for.  Stepping through it should give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SaveFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName.Trim.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim fs As New FileStream(SaveFileDialog1.FileName.Trim, FileMode.Create)
            Dim sr As New StreamWriter(fs)
            sr.Write(TextBox1.Text)
            fs.Flush()
            sr.Close()
            fs.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Trim.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim fs As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Trim, FileMode.Open)
            Dim sw As New StreamReader(fs)
            TextBox1.Text = sw.ReadToEnd
            fs.Flush()
            sw.Close()
            fs.Close()

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

this is a complete functional program if you want, you just need to drag drop a textbox, openfiledialog, and a savefiledialog.
feel free to play around with the code.
enjoy
by the way, the problem in your code is that you "must" close filestream when your done using it, doing so will release any resource such as sockets and file handles.

Answer (score 0):

The .net framework is a very powerful framework. In the same way (however) it has easy and convenient methods for simple tasks. Most individuals tend to complicate things in order to display knowledge. But less code = less processing = faster and more efficient application (sometimes) so the large above method may not be suitable. Along with that, the above mentioned method would be better off written as a sub or if returning something then a function.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("File As String", "TextAsString", Append as Boolean)
```

A **general** Example would be

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\text.text", "this is what I would like to add", False)
```

> this is what I would like to add

can be changed to the current text of a field as well.

so a more **specific** example would be

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\text.text", fullNameBox.text, True)
```

*If you would like to understand the **append** part of the code*

- By setting append = true you are allowing your application to write the text at the end of file, leaving the rest of the text already in the file intact.
- By setting append = false you will be removing and replacing all the text in the existing file with the new text

If you don't feel like writing that part of the code (though it is small) you could create a sub to handle it, however that method would be slightly different, just for etiquette. functionality would remain similar. (Using **StreamWriter**)

```
Private Sub WriteText()
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("file.txt", append as boolean)
        objWriter.WriteLine(textboxname.Text)
        objWriter.Close()
    End Sub
```

The **Specific** Example would be

```
Private Sub WriteText()
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("file.txt", False)
        objWriter.WriteLine(fullnamebox.Text)
        objWriter.Close()
    End Sub
```

then under the button_click event call:

```
writetext()
```

You can take this a step **further** as well. If you would like to create a more advabced Sub to handle any textbox and file.

Lets say you plan on having multiple separate files and multiple fields for each file (though there is a **MUCH** cleaner more elegant method) you could create a function. {*i'll explain the concept behind the function as thoroughly as possible for this example*}

*below is a more advanced sub demonstration for your above request*

```
Private Sub WriteText(Filename As String, app As Boolean, text As String)
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Filename, app)
        objWriter.WriteLine(text)
        objWriter.Close()

End Sub
```

*What this does is allows us to (on the same form - if you need it global we can discuss that another time, it's not much more complex at all) call the function and input the information as needed.*

**Sub Use -> General Sample**

```
WriteText(Filename As String, app As Boolean)
```

**Sub Use -> Specific Sample**

```
WriteText("C:\text.txt, False, fullnamebox.text)
```

But the best part about this method is you can change that to be anything as you need it. 
Let's say you have **Two Buttons* and **Two Boxes** you can have the button_event for the first button trigger the above code and the second button trigger a different code.

**Example**

```
WriteText("C:\text2.txt, False, halfnamebox.text)
```

The best part about creating your own functions and subs are **Control** I won't get into it, because it will be off topic, but you could check to be sure the textbox has text first before writing the file. This will protect the files integrity.

Hope this helps!
Richard Sites.